# Drupal 9: list ordered items in the custom-made confirmation letter

Tags: php, drupal

I use a simple custom module to send confirmation emails in Drupal 9 Commerce 2 for a custom order states. The module resides in modules/custom/my_newmodule/src/EventSubscriber and it's in a php file:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_newmodule\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\state_machine\Event\WorkflowTransitionEvent;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
    * Sends an email when the order transitions to Fulfillment.
    */
class OrderProcessSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    use StringTranslationTrait;

    /**
    * The language manager.
    *
    * @var \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface
    */
    protected $languageManager;

    /**
    * The mail manager.
    *
    * @var \Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManagerInterface
    */
    protected $mailManager;

    /**
    * Constructs a new OrderFulfillmentSubscriber object.
    *
    * @param \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager
    *   The language manager.
    * @param \Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManagerInterface $mail_manager
    *   The mail manager.
    */
    public function __construct(
    LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager,
    MailManagerInterface $mail_manager
    ) {
    $this->languageManager = $language_manager;
    $this->mailManager = $mail_manager;
    }

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events = [
        'commerce_order.process.post_transition' => ['sendEmail', -100],
    ];
    return $events;
    }




    /**
    * Sends the email.
    *
    * @param \Drupal\state_machine\Event\WorkflowTransitionEvent $event
    *   The transition event.
    */
    public function sendEmail(WorkflowTransitionEvent $event) {
    // Create the email.
    $order = $event->getEntity();
    $to = $order->getEmail();
    $myTime = $order->getPlacedTime();
    $myplaced = date("m-d-Y", $myTime);

    $params = [
        'from' => $order->getStore()->getEmail(),
        'subject' => $this->t(
        'Regarding your order [#@number]',
        ['@number' => $order->getOrderNumber()]
        ),
        'body' => ['#markup' => $this->t(
        '

Order Summary:<br><br>
Order: @number<br>
Order Date: @placed<br>
Total paid: @paid<br><br>
',
[
'@number' => $order->getOrderNumber(),
'@placed' => $myplaced,
'@paid' => $order->getTotalPaid(),
]
        )],
    ];

    // Set the language that will be used in translations.
    if ($customer = $order->getCustomer()) {
        $langcode = $customer->getPreferredLangcode();
    }
    else {
        $langcode = $this->languageManager->getDefaultLanguage()->getId();
    }

    // Send the email.
    $this->mailManager->mail('commerce', 'receipt', $to, $langcode, $params);
    }

}
```

I was able to add order number to it, order date and total paid fields, but I cannot add an ordered items list. I tried everything I know, even tried to implement some recursive function against $order->getItems() to get its fields with no luck. I don't even understand how to see the list of available fields in it. print_r gives me memory errors.

Please help me to get list of ordered items (Title, Unit price, Quantity, Total price and Image if possible) and use it in this confirmation letter. Thanks.